# How do I target the internal Android device directory as opposed to the external SDCard in AS3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, file

Google now disallows Apps to save data to the SD Card on KitKat. So I'm wondering if anyone knows how to instead target the internal Android device so I can save a mysqlite db there. I've checked a lot of the Adobe's documentation, but still haven't found a direct answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Adobe Airs File class? You could save to the application storage directory which is what adobe suggests for most file saves anyway http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory

```
var saveData:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("saveData.txt");
```